# Create Circle Stripes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photoshop-effects, effects, overlay

I want to generate circles like in this picture. It is an overlay and I need the overlay alone.

[image: circle effect example]

It looks like circles in circles each with a width and a margin of one pixel. How can I generate such a pattern in gimp or photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create circles within circles in photoshop. Here are two:

**First Method:**
Filter > Sketch > Halftone Pattern - probably defaulting on dot but can be changed to circle. Foreground color and backgrond color will determine the colors.

**Second Method:**

1. For say a 1px circle with a 1 pixel margin create an action that
   says: Expand Selection by 2 pixels then Stroke selection on the inside by 1 pixel.
2. Draw a circle, or any other shape really. Start small.
3. Click your action button and it should do 1 iteration. Click it as many times as you want to achieve the desired results.